# Changing function signature / body in RED

Tags: red

In RED we can define function using variables

```
Red [Title: "simple program"]

params: [myvar [integer!]]
body: [print [myvar]]
myfunc: function params body

myfunc 42 ; prints "42"
```

Question: how can I change function signature or body after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spec-of and body-of to access the respective blocks

```
M: Function[a "test"][Print a]
Print mold Spec-of :m ; prints [a "test"]
Append Body-of :m 5
M 4 ; prints 4 returns 5
```

For more interesting changes you may have to wait for bind to be implemented, to be able to access words in the blocks.